# builtins.ValueError: '5' is not in list

Tags: python

I am trying to read a file containing pairs of x, y values such as 556.3 439.1 when listPts[0] is called. However I am getting the following error when I am attempting to get k, the minimum y value in listPts.

> builtins.ValueError: '5' is not in list

What is the '5' referring to? I simply want to be able to print a y value like 439.1.

```
def main():
    listPts = readDataPts('Set_A.dat', 2000) 
    k = listPts.index(min(listPts, key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0])
    print(k)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what's happening is `listPts.index(x)` returns the value of `listPts` at index `x`.

Your error occurs because you're trying to get `listPts.index('5')`. I.e. you're trying to get the index using a string. Also since it's only getting `'5'` and not `'556.3'` I imagine your `readDataPts` is not returning the correct data.

For a file that looks like:

```
556.3 439.1
556.3 439.1
556.3 439.1
556.3 439.1
```

You could write corresponding code like the following:

```
import operator

def readDataPts(filename):
    listPts = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            str_vals = line.split(" ")
            listPts.append([float(str_vals[0]), float(str_vals[1])])
    return listPts

listPts = readDataPts('test.dat')
k = min(listPts, key=operator.itemgetter(1))[1]
```

This code correctly parses the file, (converts the string numbers into floats), and returns the minimum `y` value. You'll notice you don't need the `index` method at all, and since `min` returns the smallest `[x,y]` pair, you also want the index of the minimum to be `1` and not `0`.

If your file is very large (too big to get into memory), you could use a generator to yield lines directly to `min`, which would avoid reading the entire file:

```
import operator

def readDataPts(filename):
    listPts = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            str_vals = line.split(" ")
            yield [float(str_vals[0]), float(str_vals[1])]

k = min(readDataPts('test.dat'), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[1]
print(k)
```